# DelegatingFilterProxy is not assignable to javax.servlet.Filter ERROR in IntelliJ starter project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-security

First of all, I am a newbie to Spring security and Intellij IDEA. 
I have created a starter **Spring Security Project** in Intellij IDEA which uses the Spring version 3.2 and security version 3.1.

I am getting the following error in web.xml.

**org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy' is not assignable to 'javax.servlet.Filter'**

Here is my web.xml snippet.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Could someone please tell me what the issue is ? I searched in google and was not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved the issue. 
The problem was that I had 2 versions of spring jar files in the classpath. After I deleted one version, the error vanished.